# Java Discrete Mathematics Composite Function

Tags: python

Im having trouble in solving mathematical problem in discrete mathematics and I need to convert it into programming. The problem is all about composite function. I need to write a program that will calculate the given inputs by the user which are:

```
User input example
f(x) = 3x + 5
g(x) = x + 2

Computation
Replace the variable according to what is ask below
solution

Example #1
(f o g)(x) = 3x + 5
               You need to replace x of f with the equation in g(x)
              = 3(x+2)+5
              = 3x + 6 + 5
              = 3x + 11 //Final answer
```

What is the code to this problem ?

Comment: If your functions are all polynomials, you can easily do this with a polynomial class.

Comment: What are your attempts to learn programming by trying yourself first, before delegating the heavy lifting to other people?

Comment: I'm practicing programming and I've tried this many times but still I can't solve this problem.

Comment: Implementing a good polynomial class isn't something you can do in half an hour, even if it only has to handle a single variable, but it is a good programming exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it by yourself is a bit complex (although much easier if you only restrict yourself to polynomials). Fortunately, someone made `sympy`.

```
from sympy.abc import x
f = 3*x + 5
g = x + 2
g.subs({'x': f})
# => 3*x + 11
```

(Although, from what I remember of maths, this is `g∘f`, not `f∘g`. `f∘g` comes out to `3*x + 7`.)

Explanation: `(f∘g)(x)` is `f(g(x))`, i.e. the result of what happens when we take `f(x)`, and wherever it says `x` we replace it with `g(x)`: thus, `f.subs({'x': g})`.

EDIT: Bleh. Or it's the other way around. Lol. One of those two.

Comment: Thank you everyone! Much Appreciated.